# Cannot add Auth property of AWS::Serverless::Api resource conditionally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I'm attempting to add the `Auth` property to an `AWS::Serverless::Api` resource conditionally using an `Fn::If` conditional function like below so that the `ResourcePolicy` is only added when I deploy to production.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: 'My application'
Parameters:
  ProdEnvironment:
    Type: String
    Default: "false"
    Description: "Should be true or false"
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
Conditions:
  AddResourcePolicy: !Equals [!Ref ProdEnvironment, "true"]
Resources:
  RestApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: "my-api"
      Description: "My API Gateway that I can't deploy"
      DefinitionBody:
        <...>
      Auth:
        !If 
        - AddResourcePolicy
        - ApiKeyRequired: true
          InvokeRole: NONE
          ResourcePolicy:
            CustomStatements:
            - Effect: "Allow"
              Principal: "*"
              Action: "execute-api:Invoke"
              Resource: "execute-api:/*"
              Condition:
                IpAddress:
                  aws:SourceIp:
                  - "<my_approved_ip_1>"
                  - "<my_approved_ip_2>"
        - ApiKeyRequired: true
          InvokeRole: NONE
        <...>
```

Running `sam validate` on this template I get the error below

> Error: [InvalidResourceException('RestApi', "Invalid value for 'Auth'
> property")] ('RestApi', "Invalid value for 'Auth' property")

When I remove the `!If` function and add the `Auth` properties directly to the resource, the API deploys as expected with the attached resource policy.

I've also tried adding the `!If` function under the ResourcePolicy resource in combination with the `AWS::NoValue` pseudo parameter like below.

```yaml
Auth:
  ApiKeyRequired: true
  InvokeRole: NONE
  UsagePlan:
    UsagePlanName: !Join ["-", [!Ref ApiName, Basic]]
    CreateUsagePlan: PER_API
    Description: "User data management basic usage plan"
  ResourcePolicy:
    !If AddResourcePolicy    
    - CustomStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Principal: "*"
        Action: "execute-api:Invoke"
        Resource: "execute-api:/*"
        Condition:
          IpAddress:
            aws:SourceIp:
              - "<my_approved_ip_1>"
              - "<my_approved_ip_2>"
    - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Using the above snippet in my template, I don't get any errors when running `sam validate`. However, I get the error below in the CloudFormation events when running `sam deploy`.

> Invalid policy document. Please check the policy syntax and ensure that Principals are valid. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: bce87a44-07d1-49a3-a983-3370b0d0bd09; Proxy: null)

Answer (score 1):

FYI it looks like this is an open issue. See https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/1859